# Error: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested tenancy is not supported for this instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to launch an EC2 mac instance, using terraform I have been getting the error:

```
│ Error: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested tenancy is not supported for this instance type. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.│       status code: 400, request id: d749cd52-c021-41ca-a610-3f207ac82a6b
│
│   with module.ec2.aws_instance.mac_server[2],
│   on module\ec2\ec2.tf line 1, in resource "aws_instance" "mac_server":
│    1: resource "aws_instance" "mac_server" {
```

over and over again and I am not sure why . this is my ec2.tf file being used to create the instances:

```
resource "aws_instance" "mac_server" {
  ami           = "ami-044459d12a9c775f4"
  count         =  3
  instance_type = "mac1.metal"
}
```

I have checked the region I am using is eu-west-1 and the ami exists in the region and so does the configuration "mac1.metal", so not sure where I might be going wrong.

Comment: Are you launching this EC2 instance within a dedicated tenancy VPC?

Comment: If so,`mac1.metal` may not be available to be launched into a dedicated tennancy VPC (which would subsequently set the instance tenancy set to dedicated) - if you do not need it dedicated, try also setting `tenancy = "default"` or launch into a VPC with the tenancy set to default - does that work?